# Add Subtrack name attribute

Tags: arcpy, cursor, error-000732

```
import arcpy
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor("E:/Arcgis/lx.gdb/testSUBorigin", "", "", "",  "VEHICLEID A; TIME A") 
arcpy.AddField_management("testSUBorigin", "SUB", "TEXT")
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor("E:/Arcgis/lx.gdb/testSUBgetondropoffshp") 
for line in cursor:
    for row in rows: 
        if (line.VEHICLEID == row.VEHICLEID) and (line.TIME != row.TIME):
           row.SUB = "36_1"
         else:
           line.next()
```

> Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 3, in    File "d:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 3243, in AddField     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000732: Input Table: Dataset testSUBorigin does not exist or is not supported

I want to add Subtrack point name attribute according to the get_on and drop_off points,But I don't know the mistake,and I don't know whether the idea is true.I sincerely hope someone do the similar work can help me.

Comment: You should copy your code and format it instead of posting a picture of it

Comment: For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an assignment in your `if` line rather than a logical comparison.

Change the line that says:

```
if (line.VEHICLEID = row.VEHICLEID) and (line.TIME != row.TIME):
```

to:

```
if (line.VEHICLEID == row.VEHICLEID) and (line.TIME != row.TIME):
```

Further, if you're using ArcGIS 10.1 or above, it's recommended that you use the [arcpy.da.SearchCursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm), rather than arcpy.SearchCursor